# Merging dataframes based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes,

`a = {'SEX':[...], 'ENT':[...], 'XY':[...], 'RZD':[...], 'TOT':[...]}` with shape `769, 5`

and

`b = {'K':[...], 'NOM':[...], 'M':[...], SEX':[...], 'ENT':[...], 'POB':[...], 'RZD':[...], '%A':[...], '%B':[...]}` with shape `34398, 9`.

I need to merge these dataframes based on `'SEX', 'ENT', 'RZD'`. Once merged, I fill with zeros wherever values do not match. Finally, I calculate a new column `FINAL` that equals `a['%A'] * b['TOT']` like the code below:

```
local = b.merge(a, on=['ENT', 'RZD', 'SEX'], how='left')
local.fillna(0, inplace=True)
local['TOT'] = local['%A'].mul(local['TOT']).round(0)
```

The problem I am encountering is that

```
x1 = a['TOT'].sum()
```

should be equal to

```
x2 = local['TOT'].sum()
```

However, I am getting differences of nearly 6 million. This means that `x2 >> x1`

Do you recommend any way of merging these dataframes and keep consistency?

You can find the raw files [here](https://filebin.net/xqjarsf9j56mh4w8).

Comment: Without a representative minimal example of the DataFrames or their data how can we test?

Comment: I have added access to the raw files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [df.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), and see if the `how` argument helps you out. The `how` argument will alert you to where the match was made, and instead of merging by conditions you might be able to do a vector operation over the column using

```py
if df["column"] == "left_only":
  df["column"] = df["column"].str.replace("left_only", 0)

# repeat
```

Comment: I still get the 6 million difference.